# Height of General Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, big-o

I am doing Data structures and Algorithms in C++ (2nd Edition) by Tamassia and Goodrich

I could not understand the running time of height of General Tree T as O(n + sum_over_p(1 + dp)) where n is the number of nodes of T and dp is the depth of node p (Page no 276).

The concept used here is "the height of tree is the maximum depth of external nodes"

Here is the code for finding the height of tree as given in book

```
int height1(const Tree& T) {
    int h = 0;
    PositionList nodes = T.positions(); // list of all nodes
    for (Iterator q = nodes.begin(); q != nodes.end(); ++q) { 
        if (q−>isExternal())
            h = max(h, depth(T, *q)); // get max depth among leaves
    }
    return h;
}
```

Thanks!!

**Update**

The code for depth function is

```
int depth(const Tree& T, const Position& p) {
    if (p.isRoot())
        return 0; // root has depth 0
    else
        return 1 + depth(T, p.parent()); // 1 + (depth of parent)
}
```

Comment: you have not posted code for depth function ?

Comment: Please check the update in my post. Thanks!!

Comment: what do yo mean by an external node ?

Comment: @sasha - external node is a leaf node (had to look it up in Wikipedia - never heard of that term before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it you iterate over all the nodes in the tree which is `O(n)`.
For each external node you call the `depth` function which take O(1+dp) (since for the root node which is of depth 0 it takes 1 function call so hence the 1+dp), so that's the reason `sum_over_p(1 + dp)`.

The only problem is that in the code they only run `depth` for external node while in the definition it seems that they call it for every node...so i'm not sure where's the mistake.

Comment: Thanks! I guess, I got it. The for loop iterates over all the nodes. So O(n) for that. Additionally for each external node it finds its depth. 
Depth of a given node is the no of nodes from the root to the given node (excluding the given node). But for finding the depth it also iterates over the given node (So additional 1 for that). The final answer is O(n) + O(sum_over_all_p(1 + dp))   (p here is any external node) which is O(n + sum_over_p(1 + dp))

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a full binary tree **T** with **N** nodes (**N = 2^K - 1** for some **K** because **T** is full). There are exactly **N / 2** leafes in **T** each with depth equal to **K - 1**. For such trees this algorithm will run in **O(N log N)** time (computing depth takes **O(K)** for each leaf). Which is really **bad** knowing the fact that such a simple operation as computing tree height can be done in **O(N)**.

I have never read this book but I suggest changing it. *Introduction to algorithms* by Thomas H. Cormen is good for introduction.